# update Sku in using catalog_product_save_after in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, event-observer, products, sku

I try set new sku using `catalog_product_save_after` event, its continuously run this observer, But Not save the sku value.

**events.xml:**

```
<event name="catalog_product_save_after">
    <observer name="my_custom_product_save_observer" instance="Vendor\module\Observer\Productsaveafter" />
</event>
```

**Code:**

```
    <?php

    namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

    class Productsaveafter implements ObserverInterface
    {

        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
        {
            $_product = $observer->getProduct();  // you will get product object
            $_sku=$_product->getSku(); // for sku
            $this->logger->addDebug($_sku);

             $_product->setSku("testNew1");
             $_product->save();
        }
    }
```

Suggest Me, Why Its Not saved Sku value in magento 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because you are using `catalog_product_save_after`. so on product save you are again saving and again this event called so bottleneck happen. I would suggest to use different event. or Use `catalog_product_save_before` event and just set the              `$_product->setSku("testNew1");` and not save `$product` object.

Comment: I have used `catalog_product_save_before` and save `$_product->setSku("testNew1");` but SKU is not change after add product from back end side :(

Answer (score 1):

I stuck in the same situation after spending lot of time when i remove/commented  $_product->save(); it works for me.

So for the observer in Magento2 don't need to use  $_product->save();

Thanks!!!